# Inverse of numpy.dot

Tags: python, numpy, inverse

I can easily calculate something like:

```
R = numpy.column_stack([A,np.ones(len(A))]) 
M = numpy.dot(R,[k,m0])
```

where A is a simple array and k,m0 are known values.

I want something different. Having fixed R, M and k, I need to obtain m0.
Is there a way to calculate this by an inverse of the function numpy.dot()? 
Or it is only possible by rearranging the matrices?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
M = numpy.dot(R,[k,m0])
```

is performing matrix multiplication. `M = R * x`.

So to compute the inverse, you could use [`np.linalg.lstsq(R, M)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.random(5)
R = np.column_stack([A,np.ones(len(A))]) 
k = np.random.random()
m0 = np.random.random()
M = R.dot([k,m0])

(k_inferred, m0_inferred), residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(R, M)

assert np.allclose(m0, m0_inferred)
assert np.allclose(k, k_inferred)
```

Note that *both* `k` and `m0` are determined, given `M` and `R` (assuming `len(M) >= 2`).